# Class syntax, when we need or do not need symbols?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a Model class like this:

```
attr_accessible :email, :firstname, :lastname, :phones_attributes
```

and even validations in that model like this:

```
 validates :firstname, presence: true
```

Notice all of them are using that ":"  symbol before the variable names.

But then in that Model I have a method like this:

```
  def name
    [firstname, lastname].join(' ')
  end
```

So how come we didn't need to type those ":"  before variable names this time? What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see, what you pass to `attr_accessor` is not actually a variable, but rather, the name of a variable. The name of a variable is a symbol, and `:name` is the literal syntax for symbols. In your `name` method, you are actually using a variable, not just it's name, and as such, no `:`.

In more detail, `attr_accessor` is never using the variable directly. Rather, it is using methods that get the variable by name. So, it needs the name, rather than the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the symbols as simple string denoting something in a "Rails's way". So this is same as:

```
attr_accessible "email", "firstname", "lastname", "phones_attributes"
```

However in the instance method `name`, firstname and lastname are actually understood as `model_object.firstname`, `model_object.lastname` etc. Hence, no colon.

Comment: Not exactly the same, symbols are interned, while strings are not.